# A question on joint probability density functions.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know that the pdf $X$ conditional on $Y=y$ is
$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)},$$
and this can be used to calculate conditional probabilities such as $P(X>\alpha | Y>\beta)$ (for example). My question is know do we find conditional probabilities such as $P(X^2>a|Y=b)$ or things of this nature, wherein there is a transformation of the random variable $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us work with your specific example. We have
$$
P(X^{2}>a^2\mid Y=b)=P(X<-\lvert a\rvert\mid Y=b)+P(X>\lvert a\rvert\mid Y=b)
$$
Therefore we only need to deal with
$$
P(X\in A|Y=b)=\int_{x\in A} \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,b)}{f_{Y}(b)}\operatorname dx=\frac{\int_{x\in A}f_{X,Y}(x,b)\operatorname dx}{\int_{Y=b}f_{X,Y}(x,b)\operatorname dx}
$$
where 
$$
A=\{X:(X<-\lvert a\rvert)\cup (X>\lvert a\rvert)\}
$$